# Python command line: editing mistake on previous line?

Tags: python, linux, command-line, command

When using python via the command line, if I see a mistake on a previous line of a nested statement is there any way to remove or edit that line once it has already been entered?

e.g.:

```
>>> file = open("file1", "w")
>>> for line in file:
...     parts = line.split('|')   <-- example, I meant to type '\' instead
...     print parts[0:1]
...     print ";"
...     print parts[1:]
```

so rather than retyping the entire thing all over to fix one char, can I go back and edit something in hindsight?
I know I could just code it up in vim or something and have a persistent copy I can do anything I want with, but I was hoping for a handy-dandy trick with the command line.

-- thanks!

Comment: The default command line is kind of limited. You should check out [IPython](http://ipython.org/). I've had better experiences with it.

Comment: Of course, if you had to, you could redefine `parts`, but I know that's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do such a thing in the original python interpreter, however, if you use the last version of [`IPython`](http://ipython.org/), it provides a [lightweight GUI](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.11/interactive/qtconsole.html#qtconsole) (looks like a simple shell, but is a GUI in fact) which features multi-line editing, syntax highlighting and a bunch of other things. To use `IPython` GUI, run it with the `ipython qtconsole` command.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of in all the years I've been coding Python. That's what text editors are for =)

If you are an Emacs user, you can set your environment up such that the window is split into the code buffer and Python shell buffer, and then execute your entire buffer to see the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. The [Python Tutorial](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aHhhZ6yO8VIUJ%3adocs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html%20python%20command%20line%20edit&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com) says:

> Perhaps the quickest check to see whether command line editing is supported is typing Control-P to the first Python prompt you get. If it beeps, you have command line editing; see [Appendix Interactive Input](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interactive.html#tut-interacting) Editing and History Substitution for an introduction to the keys. If nothing appears to happen, or if ^P is echoed, command line editing isn’t available; you’ll only be able to use backspace to remove characters from the current line.

Comment: This just allows you to pull up the previous line, it in no way allows you to change a single line from a block and then execute that block all at once, which is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @MatToufoutu's suggestion, you might also take a look at [DreamPie](http://dreampie.sourceforge.net/), though it's just a GUI for the shell without IPython's other extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Now instead of ipython use

```
jupyter console
```

in cmd prompt